# el-form model binding with computed properties issue

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I have an issue on el-form model binding.

```
  <el-form label-position="left" label-width="170px" :model="filters" ref="filtersForm">
           <el-form-item label="TC Name" prop="tc_name">
             <el-input autocomplete="off" v-model="filters.tc_name"></el-input>
           </el-form-item>
           <el-form-item label="TC Type" prop="tc_type">
             <el-select placeholder="--Select--" v-model="filters.tc_type" multiple>
               <el-option v-for="(value, name) in tcTypeList" :label="value" :value="name"></el-option>
             </el-select>
           </el-form-item>
           <el-form-item label="Version" prop="version">
             <el-select placeholder="--Select--" v-model="filters.version" multiple>
               <el-option v-for="(value, name) in db2VersionList" :label="value" :value="name"></el-option>
             </el-select>
           </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

below is the corresponding computed property:

```
  computed: {
     filters: {
        get: function () {
          console.log('~~~~~~~~~get fileters')
          return this.$store.state.filters
        },
        set: function (value) {
          console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~filters', value)
          this.$store.commit('setFilters', value)
        }
      }
  }
```

The filters in the store is an object as below:

```
filters: {
      tc_name: '',
      tc_type: [],
      version: []   
    },
```

I supposed when I change the some values in the form, the filters' set function should be called.
I supposed the model is bidirectional. and the set method should be called. please help. thanks!!!!

I have tested it in data as below:

```
data () {
      return {
        filters : {
          tc_name: '',
          tc_type: [],
          version: [] 
        }
      }
    },
```

It works well when I changed the values in the form ,the filters object changed.

Comment: I guess the reason is `computed` watch value of itself, not the property in it. When you change `filters. tc_name`, the filters set is not trigger

Comment: @Nina0408 Aren't you getting any error as you're using same name 'filters' in data and as a computed property?

Comment: I commented out the filters in computed when I am trying it on data.

Comment: Can you try by having the filters in computed only and then putting {{ filters }} in template. As computed property is to be kept in the template to be called.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure where to put the {{filters}}, the el-form is in my template

Comment: @Nina0408 I don't think your computed property is used at all. Get or set both won't be triggered till you use it in the template. Just put it just above the el-form in the template to test.

Comment: could you please give me some hints, I am a newer to vue, so I may not get your points correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204200/discussion-between-himanshu-and-nina0408).